# Как правильно реализовать перевод числа в различные системы счисления на Python?

Tags: python, системы-счисления

В процессе изучения перевода чисел в различные системы счисления на Python, я решал задачи и застрял на пятой задачи. Я знаю, что данную задачу можно решить на листе бумаге, но хотелось бы сделать в python. У меня вопрос, как вообще работают перевод чисел в различные системы счисления на Python, а так же, как лучше решить данную задачу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задачу можно решить математически на бумажке, а можно перебирать значения x, пока равенство не получится (используя int() со втором параметром)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @MBo, что помог мне. Я разобрался

```html
for x in range(1,16):
    if int("120", x+4) - int("37",8) == int("17",10):
        print(x)
```

Comment: Вычисление второго и третьего int можно было бы вынести из цикла по-хорошему. Но наверное и так моментально считается.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да вы правы